# Select from mysql by day with different timezones (php)

Tags: php, mysql, select, timezone

I'm storing leads in a database, and each lead has a datetime field with a PST timezone based date & time.

I want my user to be able to display all leads from a certain date (e.g. today, yesterday), and choose the timezone.

E.g. if I want to see all leads that were generated yesterday in EST timezone, I need to first convert (or read) all the datetime values to EST, and then only select those who are in the target range (yesterday).

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Will it also consider day light savings?

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's [Convert_TZ(dt, from_tz, to_tz)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function.

E.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2010-03-20 12:00:00', 'EST', 'PST8PDT')
```

returns `2010-03-20 10:00:00`

edit: TO select all records that are "today in EST" you can use something like

```
SELECT
  x,y,z
FROM
  foo
WHERE
  dt >= CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), 'EST', 'PST8PDT')
  AND dt < CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), 'EST', 'PST8PDT')+Interval 1 day
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps.
But, how do I only select the leads that are today in ETS?

Comment: CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), 'EST') requires 3 parameters. you are using only two @VolkerK